# from .models import profile ImportError: cannot import name 'profile'

Tags: django, python-3.x

I used following code but got an error:

`admin.py`

```
from django.contrib import admin
from .models import profile
class profileAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):

   class Meta:
      model = profile
admin.site.register(profile,profileAdmin)
```

__________________model.py__________________________

```
from django.db import models
class profiles(models.Model):
name=models.CharField(max_length=120)
#description=models.TextField(null=True)#null value updated in data base
description=models.TextField(default='description default text')

def _unicode_(self):
#def _str_(self):
    return self.name
```

____________________________settings.py_____

```
    INSTALLED_APPS = [
            'django.contrib.admin',
            'django.contrib.auth',
            'django.contrib.contenttypes',
            'django.contrib.sessions',
            'django.contrib.messages',
            'django.contrib.staticfiles',
            'profiles',
              ]
```

Error traceback:

```
from .models import profile
ImportError: cannot import name 'profile'
```

Can anyone suggest how to fix this? I'm using python3.4

Answer (score 0):

if in your case `profile` means Profile class in models.py, then it should be:

```
from .models import Profile
```

Notice the capital 'P'. You can also share your models.py so we could see what is probably not right.

Answer (score 0):

now after some research work i have  the solution of the  problem that why someone is not able to import "profile" into admin.py.

```
____________admin.py (corrected and working for above models.py and settings.py)_____)

from django.contrib import admin
from .models import profiles #
class profileAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    class Meta:
        model = profiles
admin.site.register(profiles,profileAdmin)
```

People have misconception that one should use `from .models import Profile`   instead of `from .models import profile`  in models.py but it's not like that.
we can use any one of them depends upon what is in settings.py and models.py (in  INSTALLED_APPS  )

```
(_____________ in settings.py_________)
INSTALLED_APPS = [
        'django.contrib.admin',
        'django.contrib.auth',
        'django.contrib.contenttypes',
        'django.contrib.sessions',
        'django.contrib.messages',
        'django.contrib.staticfiles',
        'profiles',
          ]
```

i had used profiles so in my case

```
from .models import profiles
```

worked well.
and 2nd thing is  class name is profiles in models.py `class profiles(models.Model):`

```
________models.py_______
from django.db import models
class profiles(models.Model):
name=models.CharField(max_length=120)
#description=models.TextField(null=True) null value updated in data base
description=models.TextField(default='description default text')

def _unicode_(self):
#def _str_(self):
   return self.name
```

so `class Meta:
        model = profiles`

```
 so, in _______________admin.py_____________ model=profiles has used which is same as class name in ______________models.py_________

     class Meta:
        model = profiles
  admin.site.register(profiles,profileAdmin)
```

thanks... to all

regards,

Shubham Kumar(UIETH,Panjab University)

shubh2ai@gmail.com